# How does ngSPICE pick the variables to solve in a network?

Tags: ngspice

I've been thinking about how ngspice and other circuit simulators select the 'state variables' for a network. I know that this will involve some graph theory but was unable to find any references that describe just what it is that the solvers do. Any references  would help.

Comment: Go to [Laurence Nagel's UCB/ERL M520](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1975/9602.html) on SPICE2. It's all covered in there and freely available to read. (Take note of the PDF link on that Berkeley page.) Skip to 2.5 ff for a quick dash.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the only thing they *can* do is use capacitor voltage and inductor current*, or possibly capacitor charge and inductor flux.  Those are the relevant states in an electronic simulation.

* leaving out the simulation of any transmission lines and direct simulation of linear transfer functions.